# jQuery - Appending 10k Rows to a Table after AJAX call

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, performance, jquery-validation-engine

I have a web page that will receive 10k-row CSV data on which I have to call API to get more details after a successful ajax call I have to append all these 10k rows (5 columns - 4 input fields with jQuery validation rules). After successfully appending 10K rows and its validation rules web page becomes a bit slow like each button click will take 10 - 15 sec to reflect can I do anything to avoid this or reduce the time?

Things I have done:

- Replace all forEach, each loop with a basic for loop.
- Reduced validation overheads with hidden input fields.
- Used setTimeOut between 100 rows to avoid resource eating up by the browser(And tried to mimic infinity scroll by appending on 100 rows on 1-sec intervals).

```
let targetProducts = new Set();
let htmlToAppend = '', itemIndex = 0; 
let itemCodesToValidate = new Map(), itemTotalLength = responseData.body.length; 

let appendToTable = () => {
    for (; itemIndex < itemTotalLength; itemIndex++) {
        let item = responseData.body[itemIndex];
    
        if (!(targetProducts.has(item['item_code']))) {
            htmlToAppend += addTargetProductRow(
                item['item_code'],
                item['item_name'],
                item['price'],
                bulkUpdateValues[item['item_code']]?.a ?? '',
                bulkUpdateValues[item['item_code']]?.b ?? '',
                bulkUpdateValues[item['item_code']]?.c ?? '',
                bulkUpdateValues[item['item_code']]?.d ?? ''
            );
        }

        itemCodesToValidate.set(item['item_code'], 1);
        itemCodes.set(item['item_code'], 1);

        if (itemIndex + 1 < itemTotalLength && itemIndex % 100 == 0) {
            setTimeout(appendToTable, 1000);
            itemIndex++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (htmlToAppend != '') {
        $('#table_to_append tbody').append(htmlToAppend);
        addTargetProductValidationRules(itemCodesToValidate);

        htmlToAppend = '';
        itemCodesToValidate.clear();
    }

    if ($('#table_to_append tbody tr').length) {
        $('#bulk_update_button').prop('disabled', false);
    }
};

appendToTable();
```

**Nb**: Can't do pagination(I know this is dumb but it's the requirement).

Comment: You can paginate the data or use a library which does that for you like jQuery DataTable

Comment: jQuery is not for this task. Take a look at [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLhf4qy6/). It's a bit complicated (it was originally made for another question), but introduces the idea of cloning a row in the memory, and adding data to the rows in a DocumentFragment.

Comment: Is there a real use case for having 10k rows editable all at once in the same view? As @ruleboy21 mentioned, implementing a (serverside) pagination with filter/search seems much more appropriate.

Comment: Some possible improvements  A table needs to completely recalculate its entire layout every time part of it is changed, so 1) used fixed-width columns, eg a `<colgroup>` with widths set 2) use a div-based layout, not `<table>`.   3) push back on the design as 10k rows is pointless for *any* business case that can't be better provided with an alternative (eg export to excel, summary tables with drill-drown).

Comment: HTML just is not designed for this kind of use.  Write a desktop exe.

Comment: I don't see anything here using the jQuery Validation plugin.  Edited tags.   Have you tried using native HTML5 browser validation instead?